# Measure such that integrating a polynomial yields the derivative at a point

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My question was inspired by this thread: [Borel Measure such that integrating a polynomial yields the derivative at a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/borel-measure-such-that-integrating-a-polynomial-yields-the-derivative-at-a-poin)
There the requirement was only for polynomials with degree less than n. What happened if we make it true for all degree? I don't think it is true, but I don't see how to justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $\mu$. If $\mu$ exist then $p_n \to p$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ would imply that $p_n'(0) \to p'(0)$ (since $\int_0^{1}[p_n(x)-p(x)]d\mu (x) \to 0$). Take $p_n(x)=\frac {(x-1)^{n}} n$ for a counter-example.